# $kG\cong M_{n_1}(k)\times \cdots \times M_{n_r}(k)$ as vector spaces over $k$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, semi-simple-rings

I am reading Rotman's *Advanced Modern Algebra*.
In the proof of Corollary C-2.47, 
the author use the fact $kG\cong M_{n_1}(k)\times \cdots \times M_{n_r}(k)$ as **vector spaces** over $k$. 
But he only proof it as **rings** in Theorem C-2.35 and Corollary C-2.44.

I let $\theta$ be the ring isomorphism $kG\cong M_{n_1}(k)\times \cdots \times M_{n_r}(k)$ and try to prove that $\theta$ is a linear transformation. 
That is, $\theta(\lambda \cdot \sum \lambda_g g)=\lambda\cdot\theta(\sum \lambda_g g)$. But I get stuck.

Question 1. Is my direction right and how do I prove it?

Question 2. Where can I find the proof $kG\cong M_{n_1}(k)\times \cdots \times M_{n_r}(k)$ as vector spaces over $k$?

> Corollary C-2.47. If $G$ is a finite group and $k$ is an algebraically closed field whose characteristic does not divide $|G|$, 
>   then $$|G|=n_1^2+n_2^2+\cdots+n_r^2,$$
>   where the $i$th simple component $B_i$ of $kG$ consists of $n_i\times n_i$ matrices.

%

> Theorem C-2.35 (Wedderburn-Artin I). A ring $R$ is left semisimple if and only if $R$ is isomorphic to a direct product of matrix rings over division rings.

%

> Corollary C-2.44 (Molien). If $G$ is a finite group and $k$ is an algebraically closed field whose characteristic does no divide $|G|$,
>   then $$kG\cong M_{n_1}{(k)}\times \cdots \times M_{n_r}{(k)}.$$

*Proof of Corollary C-2.44:*
By Maschke's Theorem,
$kG$ is a semisimple ring,
and its simple component are isomorphic to matrix rings of the form $M_{n}{D}$,
where $D$ arises as $End_{kG}{(L)}^{\text{op}}$ for some minimal left ideal $L$ in $kG$.
Therefore, it suffices to show that $End_{kG}{(L)}^{\text{op}}=D=k$.
Now $End_{kG}{(L)}^{\text{op}}\subseteq End_{k}{(L)}^{\text{op}}$,
which is finite-dimensional over $k$ because $L$ is;
hence,
$D=End_{kG}{(L)}^{\text{op}}$ is finite-dimensional over $k$.
Each $f\in End_{kG}{(L)}$ is a $kG$-map,
hence is a $k$-map;
that is, $f(au)=af(u)$ for all $a\in k$ and $u\in L$.
Therefore, the map $\varphi_a:L\to L$,
given by $u\mapsto au$, commutes with $f$;
that is, $k$ (identified with all $\varphi_a$) is contained in $Z(D)$,
the center of $D$.
If $\delta\in D$,
then $\delta$ commutes with every element in $k$,
and so $k(\delta)$,
the subdivision ring generated by $k$ and $\delta$,
is a (commutative) field.
As $D$ is finite-dimensional over $k$,
so is $k(\delta)$;
that is, $k(\delta)$ is a finite extension of the field $k$,
and so $\delta$ is algebraic over $k$,
by Proposition A-3.84 in Part 1.
But $k$ is algebraically closed,
so that $\delta\in k$ and $D=k$.

Comment: But if the decomposition of $kG$ as a ring is the given direct product of matrix rings, it follows that $kG$ can be decomposed as a vector space in the form of the same direct product.

Comment: @Batominovski Why? They just only have the same "form". Maybe there are two isomorphic rings. They are not isomorphic as vector spaces.

Comment: I just realized that you did not use the full version of the Artin-Wedderburn Theorem.  Maybe, Rotman should have added something like the last paragraph (before examples) of this link to his text: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%E2%80%93Wedderburn_theorem.  The last example is also useful.  However, I don't remember where the proofs can be found, so maybe the references in the wiki page are helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has given a complete answer to this question, I am expanding on what I wrote.  Note that $k[G]$ is a $k$-algebra with center containing $k$.  Suppose that $D$ is a ring direct summand of $k[G]$, I claim that $D$ is a $k$-subalgebra of $k[G]$.

To prove this, we note that $D$ is a two-sided ideal of $k[G]$.  Therefore, for each $x\in k\subseteq k[G]$ and $t\in D$, we have $x\cdot t \in D$ and the fact that $k$ lies within the center of $k[G]$ implies that $D$ is an associative $k$-algebra under the multiplication induced by that of $k[G]$.  That is, in any decomposition $k[G]=D_1\oplus D_2\oplus \ldots \oplus D_n$ of $k[G]$ into a ring direct sum of simple rings $D_i$, each $D_i$ is a $k$-algebra with the same $k$-algebra structure inherited from $k[G]$.

Comment: When you say 'direct summand' you probably mean a ring summand, since vector space summands are clearly not always subalgebras.

Comment: That is what I meant.  Clarified...